# Visual Studio std::array initializer bug (2797)

Tags: c++, initializer-list, stdarray

Visual Studio has an issue at the moment such that the following won't compile, giving the error,

> error C2797: 'vec::v': list initialization inside member
>   initializer list or non-static data member initializer is not
>   implemented

```
#include <array>

template<class T, int C>
struct vec
{
    typedef T value_type;

    enum { num_components = C };

    std::array<T, C> v;

    template<typename ...Args>
    vec(Args&&... args) : v{{args...}} {}
};

template<class T>
struct vec2 : vec<T, 2>
{
    vec2(T x, T y) : vec(x, y) {}
};

int main(void)
{
    vec<float, 2> v(10.0f, 20.0f);  
}
```

The [Microsoft Connect ticket for it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/938122/list-initialization-inside-member-initializer-list-or-non-static-data-member-initializer-is-not-implemented) is closed but [there's an MSDN piece about it that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793970.aspx) recommends, "use explicit construction of inner lists".  I don't understand how to do this and the code looks quite alien to me (a beginner).

Can anyone assist with an example using std::array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case you can just add a pair of parentheses:

```
vec(Args&&... args) : v({{args...}}) {}
```

This works with VS2013 which, I suppose, you are using.

With VS2015 the code works without modifications.

Also note that for C++ conformance `vec2` should be rewritten as

```
vec2(T x, T y) : vec<T, 2>(x, y) {}
```

or

```
using base = vec<T, 2>;
vec2(T x, T y) : base(x, y) {}
```

Comment: Ah wonderful.  Thank you.  It looks absolutely horrible though.